# How to control quality and size of webP images extracted using FFmpeg?

Tags: windows-10, video, ffmpeg, webp

I am using a Windows 10 PC and I am extracting frames from video using FFmpeg as described [in this other question and answer thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1443929/960240). How do I control the size of webP files that are generated?

I tried following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i anim.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,6))" -vsync vfr img1/f%04d.jpg -preset photo
ffmpeg -i anim.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,6))" -vsync vfr img/f%04d.webp -qscale 20 -lossless false -preset photo -compression_level 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Option order matters in FFmpeg.

Options meant for an output file go before that output file and after all input files.

So, this command:

```
ffmpeg -i anim.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,6))" -vsync vfr img/f%04d.webp -qscale 20 -lossless false -preset photo -compression_level 6
```

Should be:

```
ffmpeg -i anim.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,6))" -vsync vfr -qscale 20 -lossless false -preset photo -compression_level 6 img/f%04d.webp
```

Except that quality for WebP encoder has a dedicated option `quality`, so:

```
ffmpeg -i anim.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,6))" -vsync vfr -quality 50 -lossless false -preset photo img/f%04d.webp
```

`quality` can range from 0 to 100, where higher is better. Default is 75.

`compression_level` will also modulate control and encoding speed, with 6 being slowest/best. Range is 0-6.

Comment: The documentation [says](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libwebp) that the quality option is actually called qscale. Did this change after you reply?

Comment: The answer is correct. The doc is out of date; it wasn't updated when 'quality' was added in 2014.

Comment: They both seem to work in the same way though, does it make a difference in practice? Are they aliases? Thanks

Comment: The scales are different.